# Enabling single click to open items in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

It seems that Nautilus doesn't have the usual headings under 11.04. I'm used to selecting *Edit > Preferences > Behavior* and then choosing single-click. How do we enable single-click in 11.04?

Answer (score 9):

Since the release of Ubuntu 12.10, `gconf-editor` has been officially replaced by `dconf-editor`. So the [answer by Scaine](https://askubuntu.com/a/25708/112901) will not work.

**To Enable Single-Click in Ubuntu 12 onwards:**

1. Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Copy and Paste the following line (if you don't already have it installed):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y dconf-tools
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and install the package.
4. Once installed, run **dconf-editor** in the terminal.
5. Navigate to **`org/gnome/nautilus/preferences`**
6. Find `click_policy` in the list and change it's value from `double` to `single`
7. Single Click in Nautilus has now been enabled

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like it might be a bug.  I'm installing Natty now, but in the meantime, it might be worth trying this.  Press Alt-F2 to open a run dialogue and enter `gconf-editor`.

Now scroll down to apps/nautilus/preferences and try altering the click policy there.

I've attached a screenshot.

[image: gconf-editor - Nautilus preferences]

Comment: I second that. It's probably a bug.

Comment: Excellent - that did the job...Dave

Comment: Nice one - mark the answer as "complete" please.

Comment: sadly this is still a bug on ubuntu 18.04 ... however both this answer as well as other answer using tool dconf-editor correctly perform this change ... just using nautilus preference still fails to make this change